# Is there an equivalent to Mathematicas RootApproximant function in python / scipy, numpy, sympy?

Tags: scipy, wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I am looking for an equivalent to Mathematicas RootApproximant function in python or a python lib:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html

Basically, this function finds the algebraic root of a numeric, e.g.

```
RootApproximant[1.414213] -> sqrt(2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [`sympy.nsimplify`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/simplify/simplify.html#nsimplify) (which uses `mpmath.identify` internally)

```
>>> nsimplify(1.414213, tolerance=1e-6)
√2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`mpmath.identify()`](https://mpmath.readthedocs.org/en/latest/identification.html#mpmath.identify):

```
In [295]: import mpmath as mpm

In [296]: mpm.identify(1.414213)
Out[296]: 'sqrt(((4-sqrt(0))/2))'

In [297]: mpm.identify(3.141592/2)
Out[297]: '(2**(157/183)*3**(67/183)*5**(152/183))/(7**(59/61))'

In [298]: mpm.identify(3.141592/2,['pi'])
Out[298]: 'pi*((4-sqrt(0))/8)'
```

It's obviously not as clear-cut as Mathematica's implementation, but I'm sure it beats any manual attempt to do this job. And the features are surely different (and more scarce), so you should check out the manual if it fits your needs.